# How to properly provide generic service in Angular2 bootstrap stage?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Let's presume I have a generic service like

```
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService<T> {
    navigated: EventEmitter<T> = new EventEmitter<T>();
    navigate(view: T) {
        this.navigated.emit(view);
    }
}
```

and I'd like to provide this service in my application bootstrap, how do I go about it? I played around some and came up with

```
import { NavigationService } from './navigation.service'; 
import { View } from './view';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ 
    provide(NavigationService, { useValue: new NavigationService<View>()   ])
    .then(success => console.log('Bootstrap success'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

and that appears to do the trick, but is that how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: Interesting question , what is the advantage of making such generic service ?

Comment: The idea is to provide a generic parameter for the receiver, in case I want to use this service for different apps, e.g. the app bar title could depend on the view I'm navigating to and get its text from the parameter provided by the event. The service should be unaware of what the actual parameter type is.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ NavigationService])
```

Comment: The generic type doesn't matter?